# Why Java compile is slower than Python compile?

Tags: python, java

Java compiles and generates byte code and then operates on jvm. Python similarly compiles code, generates byte code, and then operates on pvm.

However, Java compilation is considerably slower than Python compilation.

Why is that?
Is the method of generating byte code different?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401983/compilation-to-bytecode-java-vs-python-what-is-the-reason-for-the-difference-i I found similar question.

Comment: Actually, I think it is essentially the same question.   (Albeit that that question has the problem that it asks two distinct questions ...)

Answer (score -3):

Python is a Lightweight Package compiler but, Java has large package libraries...

Comment: This doesn't say anything useful.

Comment: The size of the library has nothing to do with compilation speed.